# Laravel set radio button is checked based on database value

Tags: jquery, laravel-5

I need to show the radio button checked based on database value and update the value if i change the selection of radio button and showed on form.

```
 <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio"  id="option1" name="status" value="{{ old('is_active', $site->is_active) }}" name="status"  >OFF</label>
                                <label class="radio-inline">
                                <input type="radio" id="option2" name="status" value="{{ old('is_active', $site->is_active) }}" name="status">ON</label>
```

this is inside my controller

```
 $site->update([
            'name'=>$request['name'],
            'copyright'=> $request['copyright'],
            'is_active'=>$request['status'] == 'true' ? 1 : 0,
            'message'=>$request['message'],
            'datatime'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request['datatime'])),
            'url'=>$request['url'],
            'metadata'=>$request['metadata']

        ]);
```

Comment: What's the issue?

Comment: Where is the code by which you are trying to do this?

Comment: i think this what you need {{ ($site->is_active="ON")? "checked" : "" }}

Answer (score 22, accepted):

1) NO need two name attribute.

2) you can use `{{ ($site->is_active=="0")? "checked" : "" }}` to checked based on database value .

```
<input type="radio"  id="option1" name="status" value="0"  {{ ($site->is_active=="0")? "checked" : "" }} >OFF</label>

<input type="radio" id="option2" name="status" value="1" {{ ($site->is_active=="1")? "checked" : "" }} >ON</label>
```

3) for select box do like this

```
<selec name="xx" >
<option value="1" {{ ($site->select_values=="1")? "selected" : "" }} ></option>
 .
 .
 </select>
```

**Controller :**

```
$site->update([
        'name'=>$request['name'],
        'copyright'=> $request['copyright'],
        'is_active'=>$request['status'], // == 'true' ? 1 : 0
        'message'=>$request['message'],
        'datatime'=>date('Y-m-d', strtotime($request['datatime'])),
        'url'=>$request['url'],
        'metadata'=>$request['metadata']

    ]);
```

Comment: yeah thank you...I am having another doubt for this same function if i want  to make the dropdown option as selected what i want to do instead of checked what i want to give

Comment: glad to help you @Karthiga

Comment: one more help needed ...If i want to do this dynamicaly how i use this function..

Comment: dynamically mean select option values also coming from database is it ? @Karthiga

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/141546/discussion-between-karthiga-and-jyothi).

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this

```
<div class="form-check d-inline-block">
    <input class="form-check-input" @checked(Auth::user()->gender == "Male") type="radio" name="gender" id="gender-male">
    <label class="form-check-label" for="gender-male">Male</label>
</div>
```